# How do I give a JSON string object an attribute to read?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to use JSON to select objects from a list, then delete those objects once they've been selected. I keep running into errors telling me

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

[image: error message, json file, original code]

```
path_album_list = 'C:\\Users\\steve\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\albums.json'
albums = json.load(path_album_list)
album = random.choice(albums)
print ('Today\'s soundtrack is "%s."' % album)
albums.remove(album)
json.dump(albums, path_album_list)
```

I also tried using `json.loads`, but then I got even more errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\randomizer.py", line 20, in <module>
    albums = json.loads(path_album_list)
  File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.load` takes a file object, not a string. So you need to do this:

```
path_album_list = 'C:\\Users\\steve\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\albums.json'
jsonfile = open(path_album_list, "r")
albums = json.load(jsonfile)
jsonfile.close()
# ...
jsonfile = open(path_album_list, "w")
json.dump(albums, jsonfile)
jsonfile.close()
```

Or, you can use `with` statements, but the above is probably easier to understand.

```
path_album_list = 'C:\\Users\\steve\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\albums.json'
with open(path_album_list, "r") as jsonfile:
    albums = json.load(jsonfile)
# ...
with open(path_album_list, "w") as jsonfile:
    json.dump(albums, jsonfile)
```

The reason you need to `open` the files is that `json` interacts with files, not with strings of the file path.

Comment: shouldn't `albums = json.load(file)` be `albums = json.load(jsonfile)`. Also thanks for the comment on my wrong answer, never knew jsons could be strictly arrays.

Comment: Yes, it is, my bad. Thanks! And no problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Thanks for the reply OldBunny 2800. I tried the "with statements" method, but get error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\randomizer.py", line 20, in <module>
    albums = json.load(file)
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Comment: Yeah, I edited that, it was my bad. (I should've used jsonfile, not file) @NABEF9